# No Webcam stream when embedding WebRTC in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, webrtc, wsgi, eventlet

## Environment

- Mac OSX El Capitan
- Chrome Version 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit)

## Goal

Trying to embed a **WebRTC** session in my **Flask** application.

Added the following in my HTML

```
<iframe src="https://appear.in/my_webrtc_session" width="400" height="320" frameborder="1"></iframe>
```

## Issue

When I open `https://appear.in/my_webrtc_session` in my browser, I am getting the video and audio as expected, but when embedding it in the my Flask app, NO video, BUT the Audio works!

If I create an HTML with the same code on my computer and open directly in the browser without serving it via Flask, then my session opens the webcam video stream correctly.

Any pointers?

`__init__.py`

```
    sio = socketio.Server()
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        """Serve the client-side application."""
        return render_template('index.html')

    if __name__ == "__main__"
       app = socketio.Middleware(_sio, _app)
       eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 7000)), app)
```

#### No video stream when served via Flask

[image]

#### What I expected

[image]

[image]

### `getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins` issue fixed BUT still NO VIDEO STREAM

#### Message in the Chrome console

```
This appears to be Chrome
libs.23ea13d0.js:2 ScreenShareAction: check-extension message: undefined
libs.23ea13d0.js:7 chrome: {"audio":{"optional":[{"sourceId":"default"}]},"video":{"optional":[{"sourceId":"default"},{"minWidth":640},{"maxWidth":640},{"minHeight":480},{"maxHeight":480},{"minMaxFrameRate":25},{"maxMaxFrameRate":25}]}}
libs.23ea13d0.js:8 getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.
libs.23ea13d0.js:7 chrome: {"audio":{"optional":[{"sourceId":"default"}]}}
libs.23ea13d0.js:7 chrome: {"video":true}
libs.23ea13d0.js:2 Enabling getstats.io for mysession.
libs.23ea13d0.js:2 ChromeNotifierAction: check-extension message: undefined
libs.23ea13d0.js:2 ReferenceError: cxApi is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (libs.23ea13d0.js:22)
    at Object.invoke (libs.23ea13d0.js:1)
    at Object.$get (libs.23ea13d0.js:1)
    at Object.invoke (libs.23ea13d0.js:1)
    at libs.23ea13d0.js:1
    at d (libs.23ea13d0.js:1)
    at e (libs.23ea13d0.js:1)
    at Object.invoke (libs.23ea13d0.js:1)
    at Object.$get (libs.23ea13d0.js:1)
    at Object.invoke (libs.23ea13d0.js:1)
libs.23ea13d0.js:2 Chose version -3
libs.23ea13d0.js:2 Loaded flags: {"group":"testimonials","flags":{"testimonials":true}}
libs.23ea13d0.js:2 ChromeNotifierAction: device-credentials message: Object
libs.23ea13d0.js:7 chrome: {"audio":{"optional":[{"sourceId":"default"}]},"video":{"optional":[{"sourceId":"default"},{"minWidth":640},{"maxWidth":640},{"minHeight":480},{"maxHeight":480},{"minMaxFrameRate":25},{"maxMaxFrameRate":25}]}}
libs.23ea13d0.js:2 ChromeNotifierAction: device-credentials message: ObjectdeviceCredentials: Object__proto__: Object
libs.23ea13d0.js:7 chrome: {"audio":{"optional":[{"sourceId":"default"}]}}
libs.23ea13d0.js:7 chrome: {"video":true}
libs.23ea13d0.js:2 Enabling getstats.io for mysession.
qb57:15 'Performance.webkitClearResourceTimings' is deprecated. Please use 'Performance.clearResourceTimings' instead.
```

[image]

#### Secure origin

> NOTE: Addresses partly my issue, I still don't get the video stream, BUT `getUserMedia()` issue was removed.

Created self signed certificates following [these instruction](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html)

And changed my code as follow:

```
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.wrap_ssl(eventlet.listen(('', 7000)),
                                       certfile='server.crt',
                                       keyfile='server.key',
                                       server_side=True), app)
```

Cf. [wsgi evenlet doc](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/wsgi.html)

This removed the `getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins.` issue and the camera LED on my Mac lights up. **BUT** I still don't have a video stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the size of iframe might be the problem.

I've tried your code with size `400x320`. No matter what I do I can not get the video to show up. I came to notice that there is this output in the console:`{"minWidth":640},{"maxWidth":640},{"minHeight":480},{"maxHeight":480}`. So I changed the iframe size to `640x640` and everything finally works.

Comment: yes that was it!! Thanks so much mate! I had tried 100% on width but forgot to change height! Tried `width=640px;height:480px` and it worked. Cheers